# \cparttext{} in arsclassica/classicthesis

Tags: classicthesis

I just starting typesetting the first part of my thesis proposal using Arsclassica/Classicthesis. Classicthesis provides the command `\ctparttext{Where you can put some informational part preamble text here.}`. However, it doesn't show up when I use arsclassica. Is there any way to patch this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arsclassica.sty` redefines `\part` using `\titleformat` and suppresses `\ctparttext`; one possible solution is to reincorporate it, adding it using the definitions of `classicthesis.sty`:

```
\documentclass[parts]{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\part}[display]
        {\normalfont\centering\large}%
        {\thispagestyle{empty}\partname~\MakeTextUppercase{\thepart}}{1em}%
        {\color{Maroon}\spacedallcaps}[\bigskip\normalfont\normalsize\color{Black}\begin{quote}\ct@parttext\end{quote}]

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\ctparttext{Where you can put some informational part preamble text here.}
\part{Test}

\end{document}
```

[image]